# SSRS Set Report description from expression

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Is there a way to set the report description property from either an expression or from the code? I need it to contain some reference numbers that change depending on the parameters entered. I'm going around in circles trying to find out how to do this.

Comment: have you looked at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9533630/get-sql-server-reporting-services-report-description-in-code and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reportingservices.reportrendering.report.description(v=SQL.90).aspx